# Dimension of the direct sum

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> The direct sum of two vector spaces is $\mathcal V \oplus \mathcal W =\{v+w:v\in V,w\in W\}$. Show that $\dim(\mathcal V\oplus \mathcal W)=\dim(\mathcal V)+\dim(\mathcal W)-\dim(\mathcal V\cap \mathcal W)$. Hint: use of basis sets makes it easier.

Attempt: Let $\textbf v_1,\dots,\textbf v_n$ be a basis for $\mathcal V$ and $\textbf w_1,\dots,\textbf w_m$ be a basis of $\mathcal W$. Then any vector in the direct sum can be written $a_1\textbf v_1+\dots+a_n\textbf v_n+b_1\textbf w_1+\dots+b_m\textbf w_m$. But some of them might be linear combinations, for example, $\textbf w_1=\textbf v_1+\textbf v_2$,$\textbf w_3=\textbf v_1+\textbf v_3$. Choose the smaller of the number of $w_i$ or $v_i$ that can be written as a linear combination of the others. It is clear that $w_i\in W$ and also any linear combination of the $w_i\in V$ (because it can be written as lin combo of vi's). Furthermore this forms the intersection of V & W as $c_1w_{i_1}+\dots+c_kw_{i_k}=d_1v_{j_1}+\dots+d_lv_{j_l}$ contains the vectors in both sets. Thus it spans the set and also is lin indep, forming a basis for the intersection (choosing the smaller of the number of k or l). So we can remove them from the basis set $v_1,...,v_n,w_1,...,w_m$. The number removed is the dim of $\mathcal V\cap \mathcal W$. So the total number of basis vectors left is $n+m-\dim(\mathcal V\cap \mathcal W)$.

This might not flow completely logically as I pieced the proof together bit by bit, but does it seem correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_2,\cdots,\mathbf{x}_N$ is a basis of $V\cap W$, then there shall be a basis of $V$ containing $\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_2,\cdots,\mathbf{x}_N$, say $\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_2,\cdots,\mathbf{x}_n$, and there shall also be a basis of $W$ containing $\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_2,\cdots,\mathbf{x}_N$, say $\mathbf{y}_1,\mathbf{y}_2,\cdots,\mathbf{y}_m$, where $\mathbf{y}_1=\mathbf{x}_1,\cdots,\mathbf{y}_N=\mathbf{x}_N$. Then obviously $\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_2,\cdots,\mathbf{x}_n,\mathbf{y}_{N+1},\mathbf{y}_2,\cdots,\mathbf{y}_m$ is a basis of $V+W$ (I think you should $+$ instead of $\oplus$ because you mean an internal direct sum).

Comment: ok I’m convinced